# Replacing coefficients by their absolute value in continued fraction

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, continued-fractions

Consider a generalized continued fraction $K_{n=0}^{\infty}(a_n/b_n)$ with complex coefficients $a_n, b_n \in \mathbb{C}$. From numerical experimentation in Mathematica, I found that the distance
$$
\left| \: \left| K_{n=0}^{N}(a_n/b_n) \right| - \left| K_{n=0}^{N}(|a_n| / |b_n|) \right| \: \right|
$$
seems to be quite small for $N \geq 1$ and a lot of choices of $a_n, b_n$. In fact, in my experiments it will usually be less than $1$, as may be observed for instance by taking $a_n =1, b_n =1+10 i$. I also tested this for a lot of other more complicated coefficients which are polynomials in $n$ with complex coefficients (those arose naturally from a related question which is not worth reproducing here). Is there a general statement in this direction? I would be happy to learn about any special circumstances in which such a statement might hold!

Comment: you bring up the simplest case where $a_n = a$ and $b_n = b$ are constants. Then (assuming for $n=0$ we simply have $b_0$) we find $K_{n=0}^\infty \tfrac{a_n}{b_n}$ satisfies the relation $\tfrac{1}{(x-b)/a} = x$ which is a quadratic we can solve. It can be a tad tricky to determine which root to take depending on how we define convergence, but both should have roughly the same absolute value - I would start by investigating cases where the absolute value is bounded.

Another approach is to consider that random polynomials have roots centered around the unit circle quite densely

Comment: In particular, since random polynomials of fixed degree (with coefficients chosen uniformly) tend to have roots centered around the unit circle, the relations we get from the continued fraction may satisfy the same property in many cases.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen That is an interesting thought (and fact I did not know)! Indeed, I give the example of constant coefficients but experimented with a lot of complicated polynomial formulas (which arose from a different problem as mentioned)... I wonder what happens in the general case!